# Replacement of deprecated API OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier for atomically increment/decrement variable

Tags: multithreading, c++11, atomic, macos-high-sierra, xcode9.2

I recently upgraded to `XCode 9.2(macos 10.13)`  where I noticed that apple has deprecated some API from OSAtomic like `OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier` or `OSAtomicDecrement32Barrier`. We are using these APIs to increment or decrement our variable atomically.

According to apple, for atomic increment, `atomic_fetch_add` must be used instead of `OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier`. But argument type of `OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier` and its replacement `atomic_fetch_add` is very different. Former API required `volatile int32_t *` as an input argument but latter requires `volatile atomic<_Tp>*`. We have a `int32_t` variable whose value needs to be increment or decrement atomically.

Due to legacy code, I cannot change the variable type from `int32_t` to `std::atomic<int32_t>` which is required to call `atomic_fetch_add`.

I worked out some solution but I am not sure whether it will properly increment or decrement the variable atomically in multi threaded enviroment.

For atomically increment `int32_t` variable using `OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier` current defined macro

```
#define AtomicIncrement(x)  OSAtomicIncrement32Barrier ( &(x) )
```

Proposed replaced macro with use of new API(`atomic_fetch_add`)

```
#define AtomicIncrement(x)  std::atomic<int32_t> var(x);    \
                            std::atomic_fetch_add(&var, 1); \
                            x = std::atomic_load(&var);
```

Will this work as a replacement of above macro? If not, how can I replace existing deprecated API behaviour with the new API?

Also I cannot be able to change the variable type from `int32_t` to `std::atomic<int32_t>` as I already mentioned

Comment: The macro is insufficient in many ways, and can lead to data races as you don't really protect the variable `x` itself. You could possible solve it with a macro (properly surrounded by e.g. `do { ... } while (0)`) and using a global `std::mutex`.